# Is there a non-Kac complex finite dimensional semisimple Hopf algebra?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, c-star-algebras, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

A complex (finite-dimensional) Hopf algebra is said to be a
*Kac algebra* if it is a ${\rm C^{\star}}$-algebra in such a way that the comultiplication $\Delta$ is a $\star$-homomorphism. Obviously, a (finite-dimensional) Kac algebra is a semisimple Hopf algebra, but what about the converse:

Let $H$ be a complex finite dimensional semisimple Hopf algebra.
**Question**: Is there a Kac algebra $K$ isomorphic to $H$ as Hopf algebra?
If no, what is the smallest counter-example (for the dimension), and what is the main obstruction?

Comment: I am not sure if I am not missing something, but I guess that equivalently you need to show that $H$ is a C*-algebra, right? Because it is known that for a semisimple Hopf algebra we have $S^2={\rm id}$. And if $H$ is a C*-algebra, this would mean that it defines a finite (compact) quantum group and for CQGs we have the Haar state and we know that $S^2={\rm id}$ if and only if the Haar state is tracial.

Comment: @Daniel: a finite-dimensional semisimple algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ is always a C*-algebra. Proof: by the [Artin–Wedderburn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_algebra#Classification) a finite dimensional semisimple algebra over a field $k$ is a finite product of matrix algebras over division algebras over $k$. Now over an algebraically closed field $k$ (for example the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$), there are no finite-dimensional [(associative) division algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra#Associative_division_algebras), except $k$ itself.

Comment: @Daniel: how does you sentence show that the comultiplication $\Delta$ is a $*$-homomorphism?

Comment: Oh, yes sure, I meant C*-algebra such that $\Delta$ is a $*$-homomorphism, but that's exactly what you write in the question, I just did not notice, sorry. You can ignore my comment.

Comment: I opened a similar question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433176/hopf-algebras-vs-kac-algebras